# How to convert mysql2 to psql in cucumber rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, cucumber

I am trying to convert mysql2 to postgres. When i run rake db:create I am getting the following error.

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 12.3.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending bundle exec to your command may solve this.
/home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:313:in check_for_activated_spec!' /home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:inblock in setup'
/home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in map' /home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:insetup'
/home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:107:in setup' /home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in<top (required)>'
/home/supranimbus12/tracks-2.3.0/config/boot.rb:4:in <top (required)>' /home/supranimbus12/tracks-2.3.0/config/application.rb:1:in<top (required)>'
/home/supranimbus12/tracks-2.3.0/Rakefile:4:in <top (required)>' /home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

and to migrate

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: thanks, but it throws warning message like duplicated key at line 466 ignored: "inodot"
rake aborted!

Comment: this is not rake related issue its a problem in your previous migration. you can go to that migration file and refactor it. and i think the main issue that was you facing has been resolved .?

Comment: @Dhinakaran did it helped you to resolve your issue?

Comment: @Dhinakaran feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

After adding gem pg to Gemfile.

```
gem 'pg'
```

- bundle install
- Configure database.yml,
- Create new database.
- Migrate dateabase